# Filter Firebase Database DataSnapshot children on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query the data from Firebase on Android.
And this is my data [image: my data]

And this is my Android Studio code :

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://....../myCoffee/"+phone+"");
            myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    int size= (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    txtMyCoffee.setText(""+size);
                          }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Question :  The total count of the children is 4. How would I filter the children to only count children whose "coffeeNo" is "Acoffee"?

Answer (score 4):

> Just improve your query to get only the result your are looking for:

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://....../myCoffee/"+phone+"");
Query acoffeeQuery = databaseRef.orderByChild("coffeeNo").equalTo("Acoffee");
acoffeeQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        final int size = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount();
        //size is equal to 2
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
});
```

> This way, you do not have to loop over all results and you do not have
> to implement a counter manually.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code:

```
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://....../myCoffee/" + phone);
rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int size = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String coffeeNo = ds.child("coffeeNo").getValue(String.class);
            if(coffeeNo.equals("Acoffee")) {
                size++;
            }
        }
        txtMyCoffee.setText(String.valueOf(size));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
});
```

**Edit:** Another approach is to use a simple `query` like this:

```
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://....../myCoffee/"+phone+"");
Query query = rootRef.orderByChild("coffeeNo").equalTo("Acoffee");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        txtMyCoffee.setText(String.valueOf(size));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
});
```

Your `txtMyCoffee` in both cases will display: `2`.

Comment: I Think this code will set "1" in txtMyCoffee , you need to add int size = 0 line before for loop and add txtMyCoffee.setText(size+"") after for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://....../myCoffee/"+phone+"");
        myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int count=0;
                for(DataSnapshot item: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                         String coffeeNo=item.child("coffeeNo").toString();
                         if(coffeeNo.equals("Acofee")
                              count+=1;
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Try something like this

Comment: Using "==" to compare String is not true, You must use .equals function